# Replacing all backslash with double backslashes in bash

Tags: bash, replace, backslash

I'm trying to replace all `\` with `\\` in bash, I'm doing it like this but bash gets stuck in a never-ending loop. Where am I going wrong?

```
myVar="${myVar//\//\\\\}"
```

Comment: Which version of bash? I can't reproduce an endless loop with this code.

Comment: @Barmar, ...insofar as the linked duplicate only provides a sed answer and not a PE answer, it strikes me as suboptimal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It shows how to do it in a variable, the fact that it's being put into a sed command seems secondary. I tried to find a more general dupe but failed.

Comment: Hmm. I _do_ have a working PE-based answer, but I don't think it belongs on the `sed`-centric linked duplicate, and it's distinct from what's already there.

Comment: The answer in my dupe *does* use PE: `${newstring//\\/\\\\}/g`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
echo "hello\world\hello\world" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
```

Outputs:

```
hello\\world\\hello\\world
```

Comment: True, but using `sed` is generally inefficient (for lots repeated calls with small strings) compared to [parameter expansions](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: Thanks for the resource, I am not familiar with parameter expansions. Will read about it!

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy!

Comment: Using `~` as a separator might be more readable: `'s~\\~\\\\~g'`.